# PHP Include, PHP Require Once, PHP 5.2 to 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-5.2

Godaddy was having some issues installing Wordpress onto one of my sites and they suggested I shift over to their new cpanel hosting, rather than the old one.  I did that.  Suddenly, many of my sites went down.

I started troubleshooting the issue with Godaddy and apparently the site in question was using 5.2 and since the new cpanel didn't support 5.2, certain parts of the code did not get rendered.  The specific code was:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

I changed this to:

`<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>`

It still didn't work.  Going further, the .htaccess file had the following bit of code added to it:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

I honestly don't recall the reason why I added that bit of code, but for some reason I needed it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated to both edit the code within the html page AND to edit the code within the .htaccess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `include`/`require` don't work differently in 5.2 vs 5.6. Other things do, though. There should be specific error messages indicating what the issue is - it's not that line.

Comment: Part of my troubleshooting was to change from include to require.  That didn't work.  Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned it.

When on PHP 5.2, the addhandler code in the .htaccess allowed my site to render properly by accessing the php include.  When on PHP 5.6, the addhandler code in the .htaccess was not able to process the php include.

When looking at the page source, I could see that the php include was not being read by the browser.

All else being equal, it has to do with the php include on the html and the addhandler code in the .htaccess.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Instead of editing your solution into the question, can you add your own answer instead? This will make it easier to find for other users.

Answer (score 2):

(SOLVED!)

After troubleshooting this for a significant amount of time, I found dozens of suggestions on what to add to the .htaccess file. There were numerous addhandler or addtypes that were recommended throughout the internet. I found this site:

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2492/Parse-HTML-As-PHP-Using-HTACCESS-File.html

I tried each one down the list and eventually, this is what worked:

```
`AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html`
```

I hope this can help someone else.